# Makefile error when including dependency files generated from another Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies, include

I have the current structures of directories:

- ./myFolder/

  - Makefile
  - main.c
- ./common/

  - Makefile
  - error.c
  - error.h
- ./build/

  - /common/
  - /myFolder/

`/build/common` contains the object and dependency files obtained from the compilation of the folder `common` and the equivalent for `build/myFolder`.

Basically  `/myFolder/` contains a programme that requires some function contained in `common`. Thus, the `/myFolder/Makefile` calls also the `/common/Makefile` to compile.

`./common/Makefile` is the following:

```
CC = gcc

CURRENT_DIR := $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
SOURCEDIR   := ./
SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR      := ../build/$(CURRENT_DIR)

OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS     := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

all: $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(EXECUTABLE)

-include $(DEPENDS) 

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
```

and `./myFolder/Makefile` is the following:

```
CC = gcc

INC_PATH       := -I../common/
BUILD_DIR_NAME := build
BUILDDIR       := ../$(BUILD_DIR_NAME)
CURR_DIR_NAME  := $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
SOURCEDIR      := ./
SOURCES        := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR         := $(BUILDDIR)/$(CURR_DIR_NAME)
OBJECTS        := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS        := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

COMMONDIR_NAME := common
COMMONDIR      := ../$(COMMONDIR_NAME)
SOURCESCOMMON  := $(wildcard $(COMMONDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIRCOMMON   := $(BUILDDIR)/$(COMMONDIR_NAME)
OBJECTSCOMMON  := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o, $(SOURCESCOMMON))
DEPENDSCOMMON  := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.d, $(SOURCESCOMMON))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

EXECUTABLE := ../out_file

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(EXECUTABLE)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR) clean

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTSCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@

-include $(DEPENDS) $(DEPENDSCOMMON)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRCOMMON):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIRCOMMON)

$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile| $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)
```

If I step into the folder `myFolder` and compile with `make` for the first time, everything is ok.
If then I try again I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `error.c', needed by `../build/common/error.o'.  Stop.
```

If I do `make clean` and then `make` it works.

The line causing the problem is the following:

```
-include $(DEPENDS) $(DEPENDSCOMMON)
```

particularly `$(DEPENDSCOMMON)`. With `-include $(DEPENDS)` instead of it, it works perfectly.

Now, `-` tells the Makefile not to complain if the files do not exist. If they exist they will be included and recompile your sources properly according to the dependencies. For this reason I would expect not to compile at the first attempt, but if it compiles at the first attempt, also to not generate such error (since all files exist).

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

For completeness here are the other files which are just examples:

**main.c**

```
#include "../common/error.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc<1) err_sys("some error");
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**error.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    printf("some err\n");
}
```

**error.h**

```
#ifndef _ERROR_H_
#define _ERROR_H_
#endif

/*Fatal error related to a system cal1.
* Print a message and terminate*/
void err_sys(const char *fmt,...);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to your Makefile structure.

The main problem is that you generate the dependencies in `common/Makefile` and use it in `myFolder/Makefile`. The dependencies are generated for `$(SOURCEDIR)/%.c`, e.g. `./somefile.c` which is valid only in `common`, not in `myFolder`

A related problem is that you duplicate many parts from `common/Makefile` in `myFolder/Makefile`. It doesn't make much sense to have a separate Makefile in this situation.

One way to solve this would be to build a library from the files in `common` and reference only the library from `myFolder/Makefile`. This avoids duplicating information from `common/Makefile` to `myFolder/Makefile`.
I changed your Makefiles to work this way. (There might be room for improvement, I only wanted to make it work.)

`common/Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc

CURRENT_DIR := $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
SOURCEDIR   := ./
SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR      := ../build/$(CURRENT_DIR)

LIBNAME=libcommon.a
COMMONLIB = $(OBJDIR)/$(LIBNAME)

OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS     := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all clean

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

all: $(COMMONLIB)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(COMMONLIB)

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
        $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)


$(COMMONLIB): $(OBJECTS)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
```

`myFolder/Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc

INC_PATH       := -I../common/
BUILD_DIR_NAME := build
BUILDDIR       := ../$(BUILD_DIR_NAME)
CURR_DIR_NAME  := $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
SOURCEDIR      := ./
SOURCES        := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR         := $(BUILDDIR)/$(CURR_DIR_NAME)
OBJECTS        := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS        := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

COMMONDIR_NAME := common
COMMONDIR      := ../$(COMMONDIR_NAME)

OBJDIRCOMMON   := $(BUILDDIR)/$(COMMONDIR_NAME)

LIBNAME=libcommon.a
COMMONLIB = $(OBJDIRCOMMON)/$(LIBNAME)


.PHONY: buildlib clean all

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

EXECUTABLE := ../out_file

# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(EXECUTABLE)
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR) clean

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) $(COMMONLIB)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@

-include $(DEPENDS)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@

$(COMMONLIB): FORCE
    +$(MAKE) -C $(COMMONDIR)

FORCE:
```

Note: I used the target `FORCE` with no rule as a dependency instead of declaring `$(COMMONLIB)` as `.PHONY` to force running the recursive `make`. When I tried with `.PHONY`, the executable was re-built every time without checking the time stamp of the library file.

---

Another option would be to throw away the Makefile in `common` and replace the recursive `make` call in `myFolder/Makefile` with the corresponding compile command.

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c Makefile| $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

---

**Notes**

You don't need to use the relative path `../common` in the `#include` directive when you specify this as an include directory with option `-I`.

I added `.PHONY` to declare your phony targets as such.

For automatic dependency generation and general recommendations about Makefiles I recommend to read the papers at http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/.

You might also consider using a Makefile generator like `cmake`.

If you copy&paste the Makefile code from here, make sure to replace the spaces at the beginning of the lines with a tab.

Comment: thanks but firstly is it correct to include `$(DEPENDSCOMMON)`? I will go for throwing it away, however the `common/Makefile` started its life as a way to avoid repetition. Consider I have another folder `myFolder2` with another `Makefile` and `main.c` which is a program complementary to the former. By calling the `common/Makefile` from the `myFolder/Makefile` and `myFolder2/Makefile`, if I have to change something in the `common` compilation, I can do it by applying changes in one single place, removing `common/Makefile` means to change both `myFolder/Makefile` and `myFolder2/Makefile`.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I forgot to remove a few parts. I modified the Makefile to fix this (hopefully).

Comment: Wait, why in the second section of of your answer (the one of throwing away the Makefile) in `$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(COMMONDIR)/%.c $(COMMONDIR)/Makefile| $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@`
  there is still the `common/Makefile` if it was supposed to be thrown away?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Copy&paste error, this should be `Makefile`

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I again fixed an error in the explanation of `FORCE` vs. `.PHONY`